# Tika - retrieve main content from docs

Tags: java, apache-tika

GUI utility of Apache Tika provides an option for getting main content ( apart from format text and structured text ) of the given document or the URL. I just want to know which method is responsible for extracting the main content of the docs/url. So that I can incorporate that method in my program. Also whether they are using any heuristic algorithm while extracting data from HTML pages. Because sometimes in the extracted content, I can't able to see the advertisements.

**UPDATE :** I found out that *BoilerPipeContentHandler* is responsible for it.

Comment: Have provided a solution usin boilerpipe at the below question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42589076/apache-tika-how-to-extract-html-body-with-out-header-and-footer-content

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "main content" feature in the Tika GUI is implemented using the [BoilerpipeContentHandler](http://tika.apache.org/1.0/api/org/apache/tika/parser/html/BoilerpipeContentHandler.html) class that relies on the [boilerpipe library](http://code.google.com/p/boilerpipe/) for the heavy lifting.

Comment: will it work only for HTML pages or all. Because from the Boilerpipe docs, I can see it mainly support HTML pages only.

Comment: Also can you help tell me how to control whitespaces and newline in Tika output. Because output of tika contains more whitespace and newline

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is powered by the [BodyContentHandler](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tika/trunk/tika-core/src/main/java/org/apache/tika/sax/BodyContentHandler.java), which fetches just the HTML contents of the document body. This can additionally be combined with other handlers to return just the plain text of the body, if required.

Comment: It works in all the unit tests... I'd suggest you take a look at how it's used in those, and compare that to your use

Comment: @Gagravarr "main content" is plain text with stripped boilerplate stuff (try to experiment with Tika gui to see what it is).

Answer (score 0):

```
public String[] tika_autoParser() {
    String[] result = new String[3];
    try {
        InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File(path));
        ContentHandler textHandler = new BodyContentHandler();
        Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
        AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
        ParseContext context = new ParseContext();
        parser.parse(input, textHandler, metadata, context);
        result[0] = "Title: " + metadata.get(metadata.TITLE);
        result[1] = "Body: " + textHandler.toString();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TikaException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result;
}
```