# Apache Tika how to extract html body with out header and footer content

Tags: html, parsing, apache-tika, boilerpipe

I am looking to extract entire body content of html except header and footer, however I am getting exception

> org.xml.sax.SAXException: Namespace http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml not declared

Below is my code that i have created as mentioned [at](https://tika.apache.org/1.10/examples.html#Parsing_to_XHTML)

```
import org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException;
import org.apache.tika.io.TikaInputStream;
import org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser;
import org.apache.tika.sax.BodyContentHandler;
import org.apache.tika.sax.ToHTMLContentHandler;
import org.apache.tika.sax.ToXMLContentHandler;
import org.apache.tika.sax.XHTMLContentHandler;
import org.apache.tika.sax.xpath.Matcher;
import org.apache.tika.sax.xpath.MatchingContentHandler;
import org.apache.tika.sax.xpath.XPathParser;
import org.xml.sax.ContentHandler;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.apache.tika.metadata.Metadata;

import java.io.File;
//import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;


public class NewtikaXpath {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, SAXException, TikaException {
        XPathParser xhtmlParser = new XPathParser("xhtml", XHTMLContentHandler.XHTML);
        Matcher divContentMatcher = xhtmlParser.parse("/xhtml:html/xhtml:body/xhtml:table/descendant::node()");
        ContentHandler xhandler = new MatchingContentHandler(new ToXMLContentHandler(), divContentMatcher);
        AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
        //ToHTMLContentHandler htmlhandler = new ToHTMLContentHandler();
        //ContentHandler textHandler = new BodyContentHandler();
        Metadata xmetadata = new Metadata();
        try  (InputStream stream = TikaInputStream.get(new File("///httpmoneycnncomnewsworldiidHBNQL1.html"))){
            parser.parse(stream, xhandler, xmetadata);
            System.out.println("text:\n" + xhandler.toString());
        }
    }

}
```

the exception I am getting is

```
Exception in thread "main" org.xml.sax.SAXException: Namespace http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml not declared
at org.apache.tika.sax.ToXMLContentHandler$ElementInfo.getPrefix(ToXMLContentHandler.java:62)
at org.apache.tika.sax.ToXMLContentHandler$ElementInfo.getQName(ToXMLContentHandler.java:68)
at org.apache.tika.sax.ToXMLContentHandler.startElement(ToXMLContentHandler.java:148)
at org.apache.tika.sax.ContentHandlerDecorator.startElement(ContentHandlerDecorator.java:126)
at org.apache.tika.sax.xpath.MatchingContentHandler.startElement(MatchingContentHandler.java:60)
at org.apache.tika.sax.ContentHandlerDecorator.startElement(ContentHandlerDecorator.java:126)
at org.apache.tika.sax.SecureContentHandler.startElement(SecureContentHandler.java:250)
at org.apache.tika.sax.ContentHandlerDecorator.startElement(ContentHandlerDecorator.java:126)
at org.apache.tika.sax.ContentHandlerDecorator.startElement(ContentHandlerDecorator.java:126)
at org.apache.tika.sax.ContentHandlerDecorator.startElement(ContentHandlerDecorator.java:126)
at org.apache.tika.sax.SafeContentHandler.startElement(SafeContentHandler.java:264)
at org.apache.tika.sax.XHTMLContentHandler.startElement(XHTMLContentHandler.java:255)
at org.apache.tika.sax.XHTMLContentHandler.startElement(XHTMLContentHandler.java:285)
at org.apache.tika.parser.html.HtmlHandler.startElementWithSafeAttributes(HtmlHandler.java:171)
at org.apache.tika.parser.html.HtmlHandler.startElement(HtmlHandler.java:133)
at org.apache.tika.sax.ContentHandlerDecorator.startElement(ContentHandlerDecorator.java:126)
at org.apache.tika.parser.html.XHTMLDowngradeHandler.startElement(XHTMLDowngradeHandler.java:60)
at org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.Parser.push(Parser.java:794)
at org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.Parser.rectify(Parser.java:1061)
at org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.Parser.stagc(Parser.java:1016)
at org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.HTMLScanner.scan(HTMLScanner.java:567)
at org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.Parser.parse(Parser.java:449)
at org.apache.tika.parser.html.HtmlParser.parse(HtmlParser.java:122)
at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:280)
at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:280)
at org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser.parse(AutoDetectParser.java:120)
at org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser.parse(AutoDetectParser.java:136)
at com.fractal.NewtikaXpath.main(NewtikaXpath.java:35)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

While I do understand that as per [TIKA-1215](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-1215) we should not wrap content handlers , I dont see any alternative approach to resolving this issue, as the simple bodycontenthandler is not helping, I verified a lot of stackoverflow cases similar to this but I couldn't find a solution any where. Any advice or solution or pointer is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Foudn a solution [at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23653061/how-to-extract-main-text-from-html-using-tika) based on research [boilerpipe](http://www.l3s.de/~kohlschuetter/publications/wsdm187-kohlschuetter.pdf) detection and this is integrated with apache tika and can be run with the below java code.

```
import org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException;
import org.apache.tika.io.TikaInputStream;
import org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser;
import org.apache.tika.parser.html.BoilerpipeContentHandler;
import org.apache.tika.sax.BodyContentHandler;
import org.xml.sax.ContentHandler;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.apache.tika.metadata.Metadata;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;   

public class NewtikaXpath {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, SAXException, TikaException {
        AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
        ContentHandler textHandler = new BodyContentHandler();
        Metadata xmetadata = new Metadata();
        try  (InputStream stream = TikaInputStream.get(new URL("your favourite url"))){
            parser.parse(stream, new BoilerpipeContentHandler(textHandler), xmetadata);
            System.out.println("text:\n" + textHandler.toString());
        }
    }

}
```

You can have a simple demo of boilerpipe detection [at..](https://boilerpipe-web.appspot.com/) and more information can be also available [at..](https://code.google.com/archive/p/boilerpipe/wikis/QuickStart.wiki)